# Should I use an OData server or a custom XSJS service implemenation?

Tags: javascript, api, odata, hana-xs

We are on a SAP HCP. For our application we need to provide a Web API.
We are unsure wheather to use an OData Service or a custom XSJS service implementation for this.

A few things we need to accomplish. All items also need to do a certain user authorization.

- Select data from the database
- Writing data into the database
- Providing API functions that don't perfrom CRUD operations on the database, but for example send data to another server in the background

In my understanding an OData service would only fit the first two items, but does not provide a way to do anything that is not database (CRUD) related. Is this correct?

Are there any best practices for this scenario? Any suggestions and pointings in the right direction are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

XSOData would no be able to perform non CRUD operations. With XSJS you can achieve this. I have done all of the three requirements on an on-premise
system & the same concepts should apply to HCP as well.

Sample code for executing a query & displaying data :

```
var queryString = "SELECT * FROM Table";
var connection = $.db.getConnection(); // DB Connection 
var stmt = connection.prepareStatement(queryString);
var rs = stmt.executeQuery();
var output = "";
while (rs.next()) // Column setting
{
  output += ("Col1:"+rs.getString(0)+", Col2:"+rs.getString(1)+";";
}
$.response.setBody(output);
```

To check for any GET or POST request & request parameters you can use $.request. With these you can perform your CRUD operations

You can refer to the XSJS API Reference for more info
http://help.sap.com/hana/SAP_HANA_XS_JavaScript_API_Reference_en/

For sending data to another server, one way would be by providing a web service from the second server. XSJS can make Web Request to a configured destination so you can POST data to your server. You will need to create a destination file(.xshttpdest) for accessing you server

Some sample Code:

```
var dest = $.net.http.readDestination("<package path to destination file>", "<destination file name>");
var client = new $.net.http.Client();
var req = new $.web.WebRequest($.net.http.POST, "/");
req.contentType = "application/json";
req.setBody("My data");
client.request(req, dest);
var response = client.getResponse();
```

You can find details on the below link to create a HTTP Destination & send data https://help.hana.ondemand.com/help/frameset.htm?06ca24043b0f4eb78cf39c6bc1d8a8dc.html